# How to do form validation in Magento 2?

Tags: customer, forms, form-validation

I have added custom form in customer account navigation.

Looking for code to form validation.

is there anything like form-validate like in magento1?

I have used in magento1 like below.

var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);

Like that anything is there in magento2? How can we do form validation in magento 2?

Comment: There are two types of forms in Magento2. And 2 types of validators.
Forms that are generated with knockout|ui components (e.g. checkout) and forms that are normally generated (e.g my account if I'm not mistaken).
This might help you as well. Check my answer on this question
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139711/validating-form-elements-built-via-ui-components/192772#192772 . Also look for validator.js files in your project you'll get a sense of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to add form validation to custom form by following code:

```
<form id="custom_form" action="" method="post">
    <input class="form-control" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="" data-validate="{required:true}" /></div>
    <input class="form-control" name="middlename" type="text" placeholder="" /></div>
    <input class="form-control" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="" data-validate="{required:true}" />
    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" />
    <button class="btn-confirm" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
// <![CDATA[
    {
        "#custom_form": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
// ]]>
</script>
```

You need to add  data-validate to every input fields where you want validation like below which means value is required and also validate email validation:

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
```

Comment: what should i add  inside this object "validation": {}

Comment: validation syntax

Comment: dataForm.mage('validation', {
            "firstname": {
                required:true,
                'letters-only':true
            }
        });

Comment: Is that syntax true

Comment: firstname -> represent the id of the input